# Passing a scanner from static to non-static and return a float java

Tags: java, static, java.util.scanner, floating, non-static

I am working on a project where I need to pass a scanner from the static main method to a non-static method from a text file read by the scanner and have it return a float. So far I have:

```
public class Calculator extends Stack{
public static void main (String []args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    try
    {
        s = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("numbers.txt"));
        float z = calculate (s);

    }
```

Then in my calculate method its declaration is just `public float calculate(Scanner s){` I know similar questions have been asked many times but I am just not getting it. What is throwing me off is that there is no new object being created like nodes.
Thank you.

Comment: Can i know what exact issue you face with code...

Comment: what nodes are you talking about in last line ?

Comment: It won't allow me to pass it to a non-static class and in order for stack to work (My parent class) I can't change what methods are static and which arn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the class. As the calculate() method is non-static, you need to invoke it on an instance of the class.

```
public class Calculator extends Stack{
public static void main (String []args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Calculator c = new Calculator();
    try
    {
        s = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("numbers.txt"));
        float z = c.calculate (s);

    }
```